# Display hh:mm:ss.msmsms in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am following the W3Schools tutorial on javascript Date object and trying to display the time in hh:mm:ss.msmsms format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to display a date after changing the hours, minutes, and seconds.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(07,01,01,312);
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=d;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting `07:01:01.312` (as in hh:mm:ss.msmsms) but it shows

```
Sun Feb 23 2014 07:01:01 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

How can i get javascript to displace `07:01:01.312` ?

Comment: Do you try this lib http://momentjs.com/

Comment: "following the W3C tutorial" - **NOPE**, I recognize that terrible quality code style, it most surely came from w3schools. W3Schools has absolutely no affiliation with W3C (http://w3fools.com/). On the other hand, MDN has some quite decent [tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials). (just commenting in hopes to save a soul before it is too late)

Comment: More on-topic, you will need to use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date_instances) instance methods, or momentjs.

Comment: The output of *Date.prototype.toString* is entirely implementation dependent, you'll get different formats from different implementations. To get a particular format, you must do it yourself unless you wish to rely on ES5's [toISOString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43). But likely that isn't what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to build the string in question yourself:

```
x.innerHTML = (d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds()+'.'+d.getMilliseconds()).replace(/(^|:)(\d)(?=:|\.)/g, '$10$2');
// result: 07:01:01.312
```

We build the string (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds), then run replace to add a zero in front of any lone digits.

**Edit:** Here's an explanation of the regular expression I used in `.replace()` above:

```
(^|:)(\d)(?=:|\.)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JdyOlkbtF_0Y_l7t)

Basically, it looks for (1) either the start of the string or a `:`, then (2) a single digit, then (3) another `:` or a `.`. It then replaces (1) and (2) with whatever matched (1), `0`, and the digit that matched (2). The `/g` means "do this globally." So, `7:1:1.312` becomes `07:01:01.312`.